# Using single quotes for multiple lines in VueJs

Tags: ide, sublimetext3, vuejs2

I'm trying to learn VueJs at the moment and wanted some help with the template property.

Currently, I have to enter some text in the template like this

```
template : '<div><task></task></div>'
```

But I wanted to do something like

```
template : '<div>
              <task>
              </task>
            </div>'
```

Using the later syntax gives and unexpected symbol syntax error.

Any ideas how I could use the second syntax to make the readability of the code better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use back-ticks instead:

```
template : `<div>
              <task>
              </task>
            </div>`
```